# dsacls : only delegate creation of computer object

Tags: active-directory, delegates, acl

I try to delegate to a service account only the creation of computer object on an OU.

I use the following command. But It give the right to create all object type : user, computer, OU....

```
dsacls.exe "OU=Computer,DC=ad,DC=groupe,DC=net" /I:T /G "ad\test_account:GRCCLCWSWPRPLC"
```

I'd like to give to the account only the right to create computer object.

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to grant all those rights - all user accounts should already have rights to read the objects in the OU. You just need to add the `Create Child` right.

To specify the object type of `computer`, you add a semi-colon after the permission list and then the object type. You don't really need `/I:T` either, since that's the default.

```
dsacls.exe "OU=Computer,DC=ad,DC=groupe,DC=net" /G ad\test_account:CC;computer
```

To be honest, if it's only one OU you need to modify, it's easiest to just use the GUI.